# Не парсит данные с сайта с помощью Jsoup

Tags: android, kotlin, jsoup

Программа запускается, но нужную информацию я не получаю, TextView остаётся пустым. Хочу парсить курс валюты с investing для своей программы подсчёта финансов. Разрешение к доступу в инет сделал, мнопоточность через Coroutine.

```
    fun Parsing() {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            var doc: Document? = null
                doc =  withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    Jsoup.connect("https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-rub")
                        .userAgent("Chrome/81.0.4044.138")
                        .get()
                }
                val span: Elements = doc.select("div > span.text-2xl")
            val usdText = span.text()
            runOnUiThread {
                val textViewUSD: TextView = findViewById(R.id.usd)
                textViewUSD.text = usdText
            }
        }
            }
```

Comment: в заголовке должно быть краткое описание проблемы, а не что вы там пытаетесь сделать или как провел прошлым лето

Comment: Что в дебаггере показывает? Что в логах?

Answer (score 0):

В общем с помощью ChatGPT разгадал загадку, оказывается был баг с ассинхронностью версий зависимостей coroutines, в частности kotlinx-coroutines-android  и kotlinx-coroutines-core (должны быть одной версии) указал обеим 1.0.0 и всё заработало, жаль только что INvesting.com не даёт себя парсить - но это уже другая история =)

Comment: Jsoup невиновен оказался :-D